# AWS VPC: Strange Behaviour when using NAT and Internet Gateway with Load Balancer and Private Subnets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elb, amazon-vpc

Consider the following setup based on [this document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/vpc-bastion-host.html):

- An AWS VPC with four subnets. One public and three private (one for each availability zone)
- The VPC has an Internet Gateway attached to it.
- The public subnet (10.0.1.0/24) has an Elastic Load Balancer (V2), a NAT Gateway and a Bastion server for SSH'in into the environment. The routing table for this subnet is defined as:

  `10.0.0.0/16 -> local
  0.0.0.0/0 -> igw-67e14203 (Internet Gateway)`
- The three private subnets (on in each Availability Zone) have the following routing table attached:

  `10.0.0.0/16 -> local
  0.0.0.0/0 -> igw-67e14203`

With the above setup, the load balancer works perfectly and I can reach the web server urls and applications from the public internet. However, with this setup, the servers in the private subnet (10.0.2.0/24,10.0.3.0/24,10.0.4.0/24) are not able to access anything outside the local network - not even the AWS yum repositories. 
When I change the routing table for the private subnets to:

`10.0.0.0/16 -> local
0.0.0.0/0 -> nat-0a71345c417d7758a`

- If I look at the Health Checks under Target Groups, it shows all instances in all three private subnets as healthy.
- Unless I am missing something, as the per the document [referenced above](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/vpc-bastion-host.html), the load balancer can, in fact, be connected to the private subnet(s).

The configuration for ELB is as follows:

```
"AppServerLoadBalancer": {
      "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer",
      "Properties": {
        "Scheme": "internet-facing",
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "environment",
            "Value": {
              "Ref": "Environment"
            }
          }
        ],
        "SecurityGroups": [
          {
            "Ref": "LoadBalancerSecurityGroup"
          }
        ],
        "Subnets": [
          {
            "Ref": "AppServerSubnetAZ0"
          },
          {
            "Ref": "AppServerSubnetAZ1"
          },
          {
            "Ref": "AppServerSubnetAZ2"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

The subnets `AppServerSubnetAZ0`, `AppServerSubnetAZ1` and `AppServerSubnetAZ2` are private subnets with a route that points to NAT Gateway as described earlier.

The instances in the private subnet can access outside Internet but then the LoadBalancer stops working. I start getting timeouts on the load balancer.

The Network ACL's are set properly and the *only* change in the two above scenarios is the change in the routing table.

Just can't seem to figure out what is going wrong? I would have assumed that the NAT gateway would have taken care of routing load balancer traffic as well as in the article/link above?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you attaching the Private subnet EC2 to the ELB?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the quick response. Yes, private subnets with routes to NAT Gateway. Have updated the post with relevant details.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how feasible it is to make both a NAT gateway and ELB to work for EC2 instances in Private subnet.

One work around I will suggest you is keep your Routing table

```
10.0.0.0/16 -> local
0.0.0.0/0 -> igw-67e14203 (Internet Gateway)
```

And achieve the NAT using an EC2 instance instead of NAT Gateway.

Answer (score 0):

You are misinterpreting the referenced document.

The load balancer **must** be on a public subnet, and the instances should be on a private subnet.

Why does this work when the route on the private subnet points to the Internet Gateway?  That's a trick question.  If the defaut route points to the Internet Gateway, it's not actually a private subnet any more.  It's a public subnet.

Don't think in terms of conventional networks, where it makes sense that the balancer and the instances behind it would often be on a common subnet.  VPC doesn't work that way.  There's no performance penalty for traffic across subnet boundaries within an availability zone, nor a performance advantage for traffic within a single subnet.

Comment: I agree with @Michael - sqlbot , NAT should be in public subnet and your private subnet route tables must be updated with nat id and destination as 0.0.0.0/0 if you want to connect to internet from your private subnet.